# Where can I rent a sailing boat at Orava lake?

Tags: sailing, slovakia

[Orava lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orava_(reservoir)), Slovakia is relatively close to a Polish border and I would like to go sailing there. However, I cannot find any place to rent a boat there and I don't speak Slovakian.

Where can I rent a sailing boat at Orava lake?

Answer (score 4):

I asked someone who likes boats and who does visit Slovakia regularly.

His answer came to this:
There is a rental for motor boats near Trstena.
(When you use google maps/street view you will find some jetties and boats on the lake side near road 520. I am sure it is one of them.)

You will not find any sail boats for rent in Slovakia, he and his Slovak wife have tried many times, searched online and looked around all possible bodies of water in many parts of Slovakia.
They never found any rental of sailing boats and very few sailing boats on the water at all.

He has an invitation to sail with someone owning a boat and not knowing how to sail, and every time they are both available, there is no wind at all.
The lakes that are suitable for boating are all in the mountains and very sheltered for wind.

In short, there are, most likely, no sail boats for rent anywhere in Slovakia.

Comment: Thanks! I have pinged several hotels close to and one of them rents Sportina 682 for 35euro / day. That's a decent offer but strange they have only one boat in the offer. Or not strange after reading your answer.

Comment: I found a place you were talking about: https://goo.gl/kwcYe0. In fact looks like place for renting a jetty or a boat, definitely not for sailing.

Comment: Surprisingly, I found there are places with boats there: https://goo.gl/u4wlU3. I just need to check if they are for rent.

Comment: Please let us know when you do find a sail boat for rent, I know someone would love to rent it on his next trip to Slovakia.